# ElasticSearch Cluster Set Up : master_not_discovered_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, deployment, cluster-computing

I have 2 instances and My ES Configuration is something like this

Config -1

```
           cluster.name: my-cluster
           node.name: node1
           discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com", "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
           discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
           node.master: true
           node.data: true 
           network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

Config -2

```
           cluster.name: my-cluster
           node.name: node2
           discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com", "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
           discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
           node.master: false
           node.data: true
           network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

On slave server I am get master_not_discovered_exception,i can ping master from slave.

I want to make one of them as dedicated master.

Comment: since only one of your nodes can be master, you must set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1` and not 2 otherwise your cluster will not work.

Comment: @val Is it mandatory to configure min master nodes?Also I making a slight change in above configuration...now on slave only i am getting this exception

Comment: It is mandatory to configure that setting properly... if you have only one master you cannot enforce to have minimum two masters :-)

Comment: @val..no thats true..but what if i comment this

Comment: What error do you get now?

Comment: @Val On commenting min_master nodes ....on my second server i get Master_not_found_exception

Comment: ok then it means that node2 cannot see node1. On node2 can you ping node1 ?

Comment: @val..yes,i can ping...before this i had no dedicated master..then things were working fine..on both servers while checking cluster state i was getting both nodes..now i added node.master and node.data and min_master_nodes..it works on Master server..not on slave

Comment: @Val.. Any suggestion?:|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144530/discussion-between-groovy-and-val).

Comment: So if you set data and master=true on both nodes it works? but not when only node1 is master?

Comment: Why you are not using `cloud-aws` plugin ? Since you are working with EC2 , it is easy to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both nodes can communicate with each other on port `9300` viz the firewall rules between these instances are set to allow `inbound TCP` traffic on port `9300`.